# Weird Overlap of Elements in iOS (PhoneGap)

Tags: ios, css, cordova, uiwebview, overlap

I'm working on an iOS/PhoneGap project. I have a weird overlap issue in iOS (screenshot from iPad):

[image: Screenshot from iOS]

The "Select Status" popover is `position: absolute, z-index: 35`. The website link is doesn't have a position specified (so `static`) and no z-index specified.

*It makes no matter if the address link is random text with no link, or a link (as captured), it still happens.*

Here's what it looks like in Chrome (as expected) (taken on a retina Mac, so it's huge):

[image: Picture is correct is Chrome]

I have tried tweaking the z-indexes all day long in Safari's console on the iPad with no effect. ***It does not seem to be a "simple" z-index issue.*** So please don't just say "adjust z-index."

**[edit]** To be specific, I have tried setting the `z-index` of the popover to `5000` and the web address to `-10` (giving it several different `position`s), and I have checked every ancestor of both elements to make sure none of them have `z-index`es (and they didn't). I even tried giving a couple of the ancestors of the popover `position`s and `z-index`es. Nothing ever changed. (And lest it is brought up, I did try changing `color`s and stuff, just to make sure my changes *were* making it to the page.)

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way we can take a look at the actual source code?

Comment: Forgive me, but since you didn't specify that you have tried negative values, I suggest to try setting address link's position to absolute , and z-index to a negative value.

Comment: It's not on anything public at the moment, and it's password protected even if I made it public... Plus, I'd have to give you the actual app for you to reproduce the actual issue, and that would be super complicated, thanks to Apple's provisioning policy!

Comment: @codeqi Sorry, I didn't. But I tried `-10` for the address (setting it to both `absolute` and `relative`) and `5000` for the popover.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836451/z-index-not-working-very-well-in-ipad . Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this has been plaguing our project for about a month, but I think I solved it. I haven't thoroughly tested the theory, but it has solved all of our issues so far.

If you remember way back in the days of IE7, there was a weird z-index bug, and the only way you could fix it was to find ancestors of the offending elements that were siblings and adjust *their* z-indexes.

For example, let's say this is my markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <button>
            Click Me

            <div class="dropdown">
                <ul>
                    <li>This</li>
                    ...
                </ul>
            </div>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="col1">...</div>
        <div class="col2">...</div>
        <div class="col3">www.example.com</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and like in my images, it looks correct in Chrome, but in iOS, www.example.com is above `.dropdown`.

Their ancestors that are siblings are `.header` and `.content`. If I adjust the `z-index` (while setting the `position` to `relative`, of course) of `.header` to be higher than `.content`, it fixed the issue.

Hope that makes sense and helps anything that might come to this page...

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! For anyone else: set `.header { z-index: 2; }` and `.content { z-index: 1; }` in the example above.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying to say, haha... guess I could have been more straightforward. I was just mystified that this is so reminiscent of the bad ol' IE7 days.

Comment: Legend, fixed my problem too.